# Submitting JQuery Function from Input type=button onClick

Tags: jquery, button, onclick, submit

I have this JQuery Methodology that I am using within several forms in the same document, just with different Function Names.
I need to be able to call specific forms from an `<input type=button onClick="??">`
I can't get it to work.

Here is the Script I need to call/change:

```
function ConvertFormToJSON(form)
{
  var array = $(form).serializeArray();
  var json = {};
  json["comm_type"] = "SFTP";
  jQuery.each(array, function() {
    json[this.name] = this.value || '';
  });
  return json;
}

$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $("body").css("cursor","wait");
}).ajaxStop(function() {
  $("body").css("cursor","default");
})

$(document).ready(function()  {
  $( "#sftp_advanced_fieldset").puifieldset({toggleable: true, collapsed: true, toggleDuration: 0});
  $( "#sftp_help").puifieldset({toggleable: true, collapsed: true, toggleDuration: 0});

  $("#test_sftp").bind('submit', function(event){
    // event.preventDefault(); //Why would you cancel default action of submit?                    
    var jsonRequest = JSON.stringify(ConvertFormToJSON(this));
    //alert(jsonRequest);
    $("#results").html("");

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "TEST",                        
      data: jsonRequest,
      dataType: "json"
    }).always(function(results) {
      var jsonResults = JSON.stringify(results);
      if (results.status == "Succeeded") {
        jQuery("#results").html("<h1 style=\"color: #00cc00; \">" + results.status + "</h1>");
    });
```

etc...., etc....

Of course with the `$("#test_sftp").bind('submit', function(event){`
It works fine from a `input type="submit"` but I don't want to do it that way.

Any help is great appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="button" value="Button" onclick="javascript:doSomething()">`

Will work just fine